# Open spyder in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, spyder

I want to open spyder(Python IDE) in ubuntu.

Normally I would write "spyder" in the shell, and it would open the spyder IDE.

Now when I write spyder in the shell, it just new lines, and nothing happens(similar to pressing 'enter').

--- How do I get my spyder back?

EDIT - I get no errors, it just skips to the next line.

Comment: You don't get an error about command not being found? Then it sounds like `spyder` is having problems and you should look for a log file from it or see if there's a "verbose" or "don't background" option that might let you see more about what is happening.

Comment: There is no errors, how would you recommend debugging in ubuntu?

Comment: Look for the flags I suggested then go look and see if `spyder` has any debugging guides/suggestions on the site and/or an irc or similar channel for support.

Answer (score 8):

If typing "spyder" doesn't work, you might want to try typing "spyder3" in case you installed the spyder3 version. Below is what worked for me in my Ubuntu system.

To install spyder via pip (my python version is 3.6.2), I used:

```
 pip install spyder
```

Then, I had to install another package:

```
 pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Finally, to open the Spyder window, I typed into my terminal:

```
 spyder3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply have to update spyder.

If you are NOT using anaconda:

```
pip install --update spyder
```

Or, if you are in anaconda:

```
conda update spyder
```

I had the same issue as yours, with also a message in the command line saying:

```
Spyder is already running. If you want to open a new 
instance, please pass to it the --new-instance option
```

The above update allowed me to open spyder from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and found [this post on it in an askubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/a/638035). It suggested using `sudo apt-get purge spyder` to delete any faulty configuration files and then reinstall with `sudo apt-get install spyder`.  I found it worked, and spyder reopened with my previous files on the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

in Ubuntu, just go to your,

```
 cd home/<your account>
```

then go to .spyder2 folder

```
cd spyder2
```

should get you there

in terminal, type `la` in terminal(`ls` doesn't show the hidden files ) and use,

```
rm -f spyder.lock
```

to delete

Answer (score 0):

To launch spyder in `bash` console, just enter:

```
spyder .
```

in the `bash` console.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to install spyder is:

```
sudo apt install spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

now uninstall spyder and do this :

```
#first install spyder
sudo apt install spyder

#updata your conda
conda update anaconda

#updata spyder
conda update spyder

#then write this and wait
spyder
```

use this [link](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#linux)
or if you do not have conda use this[linl=k](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)