# Spyder not finding modules installed with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a newly installed Anaconda and tried to run an old code that uses `scipy`, `numpy` and `os` using Spyder 3.2.6. and get an error. When trying to import `numpy` from the IPythoin console I get

```
import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-0aa0b027fcb6>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

The `os` module however does get imported and works. I tried running python importing both `scipy` and `numpy` and I don't have any issue. I'm running just one Anaconda environment, so there's no mistake there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Anaconda Prompt:
Try installing Spyder into that environment via "conda install spyder", and then run spyder from that environment via "spyder".

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and using the terminal. I'm quite sure my spyder installation was done with anaconda, but I tried doing copnda install spyder and I get `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: -spyder`. And a list of my channels. I'll update if I have any progress.

Comment: Update: `conda install -c conda-forge spyder` did install something. Then, following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077826/open-spyder-in-ubuntu and running `spyder` in terminal doesn't open spyder, but locks the terminal. I'll try reinstalling anaconda.

Comment: One thing to try from that other question is trying to purge Spyder.  You could also try checking "conda install -c anaconda spyder".  What version of Spyder are you trying to use?  Looks like the most recent is 3.3.1.

Comment: I purged and uninstalled both anaconda and spyder, and reinstalled anaconda. I run `conda install spyder` and `conda updete spyder`, and now when I run `spyder` in terminal at least it tries to open it. But now it seems it fails with the message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. No luck for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I just wrote this line in *Anaconda Prompt instead of OS command prompt*:

```
pip install <module>
```

It's obvious that `<module>` will be replaced by the desired module name.